# An unhandled win32 exceprion occurred in w3wp.exe

Tags: .net, iis-7

I am getting this error when the application is run in IIS, but in normal browser, it is ok. My Application is built in .net 2.0, Windows 2008 server, and Oracle 10g. Please help.

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and then rework your question (as it stands there is insufficient information to help you).

Answer (score 1):

Possibly take a look at:

[System.Data.OracleClient.dll crashes w3wp.exe on w2k8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949516/system-data-oracleclient-dll-crashes-w3wp-exe-on-w2k8)

Or Microsoft's own discussion on w3wp.exe: 
[Unhandled exceptions cause ASP.NET-based applications to unexpectedly quit in the .NET Framework 2.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911816)