# System.Data.OracleClient.dll crashes w3wp.exe on w2k8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle10g, windows-server-2008, windbg

I'm using Windbg to debug an error that is happening in a website that we have on a Windows Server 2008, IIS7 environment. I've set the symbol path to "SRV*c:\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols"

Then I browse the website, which takes me to the login page. In that moment I attach Windbg to the w3wp.exe process. I then enter my credentials into the login page and submit the form, which is the process that is giving problems. I then select Windbg -> Debug -> Go Unhandled Exception, which outputs the following in the console:

```
ModLoad: 6d720000 6d835000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Data.OracleC#\fb8da45f3873169a502db3cb492b25a0\System.Data.OracleClient.ni.dll  
ModLoad: 06a80000 06afb000   System.Data.OracleClient.dll  
ModLoad: 06b00000 06b7b000   System.Data.OracleClient.dll  
ModLoad: 06a80000 06afb000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32  \System.Data.OracleClient\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll
ModLoad: 06b80000 06be1000   C:\XEClient\bin\oci.dll  
ModLoad: 7c340000 7c396000   C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR71.dll  
ModLoad: 06c50000 09af9000   C:\XEClient\bin\OraOCIXE10.dll  
ModLoad: 739d0000 73a02000   C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll  
ModLoad: 73990000 739cd000   C:\Windows\system32\OLEACC.dll  
Critical error detected c0000374
```

After that I hit F10 many times until the following is print to the output and debugger keep thinking:

```
eax=05cbe288 ebx=00000000 ecx=76e47463 edx=05cbe025 esi=001a0000 edi=01fb3210  
eip=76ebfaf3 esp=05cbe274 ebp=05cbe2f0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc  
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246  
ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x56:
76ebfaf3 e89063fbff      call    ntdll!RtlRaiseException (76e75e88)  
0:023> p
(5b0.b5c): Unknown exception - code c0000374 (first chance)
```

Once debugger finally continues, it prints the following to the console:

```
WARNING: Step/trace thread exited
eax=000000c0 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000400 edx=00000000 esi=04420000 edi=000005b0
eip=76e75e74 esp=05cbdd88 ebp=05cbde0c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000202
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
76e75e74 c3              ret
```

Then w3wp.exe dies.

My question is... How can I get some more info about the error? I already knew it was related to Oracle because errors dissapear if I just put the following in the global.asax Application_Start method:

`try{

    new OracleConnection().ConnectionString = "anything";

}catch(Exception ex){

}`

That simple line of code fixes the application... Incredible, right?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE: 2011.02.09 15:46**
The web app is working fine in Windows XP & Windows Server 2003, IIS 5 & 6.

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    Logger.LogMessage("Application_Start", "Started");
}

protected void Application_End()
{
    Logger.LogMessage("Application_End", "ended");  
}
```

LoginController.cs

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
            string connString = "Data Source=IP:Port/Service;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user; Password=user;Unicode=True";
            System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection dbConn = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection();
            dbConn.ConnectionString = connString;

            System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand dbComm = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand();
            dbComm.CommandText = "user.package.procedure";
            dbComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            dbComm.Connection = dbConn;
            dbComm.Parameters.Add("MyParam", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.Number);
            dbComm.Parameters["MyParam"].Value = DBNull.Value;


            System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter dbAdap = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter(dbComm);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try {
                Logger.LogMessage("TEST", "1");
                dbConn.Open();
                Logger.LogMessage("TEST", "2");
                dbAdap.Fill(ds);
                Logger.LogMessage("TEST", "3");
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                Logger.LogMessage("TEST", "4");
            } finally {
                Logger.LogMessage("TEST", "5");
                if(dbConn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) {
                    dbConn.Close();
                }
                dbConn.Dispose();
            }           
            return View();
}
```

Now the curious thing: You install the website. Browse it. You're taken to Login page. w3wp.exe is now live. Enter credentials an submit form. Everything is ok. You log on to the site and start navigating through its pages. All pages have Oracle interaction.

Stop browsing.

Some minutes after you stopped browsing, w3wp.exe dies. It is ok. It must happen unless you specify otherwise.

Browse again. You are taken to login page and w3wp.exe is live again. Enter credentials and click submit. Code stops when executing the line "dbConn.Open();"

What I see in the log is:

- Application_Start - Started
- TEST - 1

After 1 minute or so, I see the following in the log:

- Application_Start - Started
- TEST - 1

After that, application just display the "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" page.

Log does not show "TEST - 4" cause of the catch neither it shows "Application_End - Ended" cause of the global.asax method.

EventViewer is not helpful, since it only says that w3wp.exe has failed.

Now the even more courious thing. If I apply following line in Application_Start method, application works:

`try{
                    new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection().ConnectionString = "anything";
                }catch(Exception ex){
                }`

It throws an exception saying that connection string format is invalid. But application works.

What am I expecting from Windbg? I'm expecting it to gives me something I can browse in google and then google takes me to some blog where a guy wrote that "you have to reinstall Oracle 10g" or something like that...

Thanks again.

Comment: You don't have by chance the code-behind of the login page

Comment: Hi @rene, please see my update with the code

Comment: @Pedro Rivera this win2008 box is that 64bits? The two system where it did work are those 32bits? I assume TNSPING and logon with sqlplus al works flawlessly? Can you enable extra logging for the OCI client?

Comment: Hi @rene, how do I enable extra logging for the OCI client?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A57673_01/DOC/net/doc/NWTR23/apa.htm#cli.prm. You might also consider changing the title to "System.Data.OracleClient.dll crashes wp3wp.exe on w2k8" because it better reflects what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi @rene I updated the title... let me try to understand that OCI client stuff... It seems I need to download a "Listener" utility, which I dont find any link to download... and it seems also that I need to have control over the system where Database is, which I dont have.. Let me see what else can I do before getting deeper into the OCI client... thanks

Comment: @Pedro Rivera: Hmmm, that is not what I would expect. If you open a commamnd prompt on the webserver what says: SET ORACLE_HOME? That gives you the path to the oracle client stuff in that folder (I believe under .../Admin/ there is file called sqlnet.ora, make your adjustments there.

Comment: Hi @rene : I'm lost here... I start reading the document you point, which talks about .ORA files I dont know... there is a "How to Set Trace Parameters" link that took me to "To turn tracing on and off, use the TRACE command of the Listener Control Utility"... Now, by your comment it seems I'm totally wrong... could you please guide me? So, I open cmd in the webserver OS and then enter what?

Comment: @Pedro Rivera SET ORACLE_HOME that should give you a path.

Comment: ok @rene ... that command ouput "Environment variable ORACLE_HOME not defined" ... but if what we need is Oracle's directory, it is "C:\XEClient", the oci.dll is under "C:\XEClient\bin" folder ... but there is no Admin folder nor sqlnet.ora file under this directory, even at all the "C:" drive... there is no such file under the WIndows XP, Windows Server 2003 systems either and it works ok... Will continue trying and will let you know... thanks again

Comment: @Pedro Rivera http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featDebug.htm#sthref590 You have to modify the registry and set the follwing values: TraceFileName="c:\[path]\[under]\[inetpub]\odp.log TraceLevel=63 TraceOption=1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a managed exception

Steps to diagnose managed code Exception

1. Attach to the process
2. Issue the command `.loadby sos
   mscorwks` for up to .NET 3.5 and for .NET 4.0 use `.loadby sos clr`
3. Next Issue the command `sxe -c "!clrstack;!pe;KB" clr ;g`

This would break the debugger when there is a managed exception and provide you with managed /native call-stack as well as exception details.

Comment: Hi @Naveen, I followed these steps: browse to be taken to login page. Attach to the process. type your first command. type your second command. Submit the form. After a couple of seconds, the following is printed: The current thread is unmanaged
Syntax error at '";g'  After that, nothing happens. After 3 minutes I press F10 and we are at the previous "Critical error" stuff again. Am I missing some step?

Comment: see if you can have a stacktrace

Comment: @Pedro @rene The command was wrong. I updated the answer with the correct command sxe -c "!clrstack;!pe;KB" clr ;g

Comment: Thanks @Naveen I followed the steps... unfortunely it had the same result as Debug -> Go Unhandled Exception... it just displayed "Critical error detected c0000374" and, after hit F10 many times, "Unknown exception - code c0000374 (first chance)" ... lets keep trying

Comment: @Pedro Can you do a "kb" and "!gle" on  Unhandled Exception? Probably the call-stack might give some insights.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by "w3wp.exe" dies. Can you see in Windows event log if there is any IIS error?

Debug Diag crash rule can be a better way to capture crash dumps if you are not familiar with live debugging,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919789

Analyzing crash dumps is a clearer approach for crash issues.